# Semantic guess the number game errors - Python3.x

Tags: python-3.x, file, if-statement, file-io, numbers

I am 11 years old and am keen programmer learning Python.

1) I am programming a guess the number game and when I ask the user if they want to play again, I get a semantic error (I think this is the correct way to describe it) where if I input "no", "n", "NO" or "N", the if statement is still executed, causing the `loop()` function to run again, after calculating scores. Take a look at the following image (sorry about the cluttered windows).

Play again error: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsEyw.png`

Here is a link to the rest of the program:
`https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f9be138e07c569b8721b990293d92314` (I only have 8 reputation points) , but I am looking at just this snippet:

```
def play_again():
    again = input("\nWould you like to play again? y/n " + prompt)
    if again.upper() == "Y" or "YES":
        global gu_num
        percent = gu_num * 10
        score = 100 - percent
        highscores = [{round: (score)}]
        current_score = {round: (score)}
        highscores.append(current_score)
        print("Lets see if you can beat your score of " + str(current_score[round]) + ".\nHere we go!")
        gu_num = 0
        loop()
    elif again.upper() == "N" or "NO":
        print("Ok then.\nThank you for playing Guess The Number and I hope to see you again soon!\nThis game was created and devoloped by Kiran Patel (me), age 12. If you liked this game or want to talk to me about -->anything<--, please do email me at kiran@inteleyes.com. It'll make me happy! Thank you for playing Guess the number with me.\n\n program was developed by Kiran Patel in 2017 ad.")
        input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit")
        quit()
    else:
        print("Sorry, I don't understand. Please try again:")
        play_again()
```

2) I'm having a similar problem with the part of my code which starts to handle files. When I input a 'no' (same `if` expression) the program will execute the part of that if statement which creates the file (take a look at this image: [file saving result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbpUr.png) and this image: [file operations code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNN4R.png)). Note that the 'file operations code' image prints out the file-save error message because I hadn't given perms to write in prog'/files folder. I know it has tried to save the file because of the error message that was printed out (I intended the error message to be printed out).

3) Also, does anyone know what `#!/usr/bin/python` means? I know its hashtagged out, but I have seen it before like this and I was wondering what it means.

As always, ANY help  will
be appreaciated, so please don't hesitate on adding something that is not directly relevant to the question, because I may well have missed it (unless it is completely irrelevant).

Once again, thanks in advance for your help.

From Kiran

Comment: Have you thought of reading a programming tutorial?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: Regarding the wrong branches of conditional statement being executed - drop all logic and simply print the expressions you are trying to test in your conditions, i.e. `again.upper()`. This should give you an idea of why your condition is evaluated incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here (and on every line that looks like it):

```
    if again.upper() == "Y" or "YES":
```

Here's what you (reasonably) assume it's doing (This is how you would fix it, btw):

```
    if (again.upper() == "Y") or (again.upper() == "YES"):
```

Here's what it's actually doing:

```
    if (again.upper() == "Y") or "YES":
```

So let's say that you typed `Q` at the prompt. As Python reads along the line, it sees the first comparison operator, `==`, and compares just the two things on either side of it: `"Q"` and `"Y"`. "Those are not equal", thinks Python, and moves on to the next part: comparing `False` - the answer to the first part - with `"YES"`.

In Python, if something exists and isn't `False` or `0` or something similar, it gets treated as `True`.  "`False` is False, but `"YES"` is a perfectly valid string", thinks Python. "and the `or` operator means that if either of these two things is True, the whole thing is True, so this must all be true and I should run this block of code now." And so it does, every time, no matter what you type.

As a general rule, when you're doing these kinds of tests, it's only safe to do one comparison at a time. Any more than that and it's time to bring in the parentheses.

Also, regarding `#!/usr/bin/python`: the `#!` is called a [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), and it's not part of Python at all - it's part of your operating system (assuming your operating system isn't Windows). It says to your OS: "This may look like an ordinary text file, but it's actually a script, which you should run using the program located at `/usr/bin/python`".

Comment: Thank you, Will T, for your very detailed and amazing answer. I have always wanted help with this and you were the one who gave it to me. I see your logic about the line of code. Also, I knew that the /usr/bin/python was a path but I just didn't know what it did. Once again thank you for explaining it to me in an understandable way.

Comment: can I just ask about the Shebang? As soon as the user tries to open the file without specifying a default OS program, does the Shebang determine what program the script is opened with? Or will it override the default OS program?

Comment: Hey Kiran, regarding the shebang, it really only has an effect when you're running the script on the command line. What it lets you do is go into the folder where you've saved this file using your terminal program and enter `./number_game.py` or whatever the name of the file is, and the terminal will know to execute it as a script. If you're opening it "normally" (normally for 2017, that is) using the GUI, it won't make a difference. Also, it won't make a difference on Windows, unless you're using the Linux Subsystem for Windows, which is really cool and you should check it out.